# Will runloop block GCD?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I add a timer on Thread A and start the runloop, after that I dispatch_async a Method_Foo on Thread A, and Method_Foo doesn't run. What I guessing is that the dispatch methods will be blocked by the runLoop on that thread but I not sure. Is that true or am I missing something?

More details:

In the network layer I use delegate to notify network status, the *_delegateQueue* is from an global instance, let's say **Thread_A**. And this **socket:didConnectToHost:port:** method is running in a Thread_B.

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(uint16_t)port
{
  // called when connected to server
  ...
  dispatch_async(_delegateQueue, ^{
    // this runs in Thread_A to notify network status
    [theDelegate socketConnection:self didChangeStatus:YES];
  });
  ...
}
```

Then in the upper layer there's a class run the **_startReconnectingProcess** method after disconnected with the server in **Thread_A**. To make the timer to work, I start the runLoop in **Thread_A**.

```
// runs in Thread_A to start reconnection process
- (void)_startReconnectingProcess
{
  if (self.reconnectionTimer || _forceDisconnection == YES) return;

  self.reconnectionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kReconnectionTimeInterval target:self selector:@selector(_reconnect) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
  [runLoop addTimer:self.reconnectionTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
  // run the runLoop in Thread_A
  [runLoop run];
  // after the runLoop start, the dispatch_async method in the network layer doesn't work

  self.reconnectionCount = 0;
}
```

So what happens is that **when the timer starts, the method *[theDelegate socketConnection:self didChangeStatus:YES]* never be called, which should.**

Comment: How do you 'dispatch_async a Method_Foo on Thread A' ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Dispatch queues are one of the input sources to the run loop; there's no question of them being "blocked" by it. Please add some code and explain your problem in more detail.